# GCC link error [ cygwin64 ] .. help anyone?

Tags: gcc, reference, linker, undefined

I have some code doing terminal ansi color under VS2012 I was going to put into some cygwin terminal code - re-use the common win32 modules. Seems it should be simple. But GCC won't match the function names...
Odd.

I have module 1
ansicolorbasic.cpp which i've compiled to ansicolorbasic.o

$ nm ansicolorbasic.o -C
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 N .debug_abbrev
0000000000000000 N .debug_aranges
0000000000000000 N .debug_frame
0000000000000000 N .debug_info
0000000000000000 N .debug_line
0000000000000000 N .debug_line_str
0000000000000000 N .debug_str
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
0000000000000000 B CONSOLE_BUFFER
0000000000000000 D CONSOLE_FG_COLORS_0_15
00000000000000a7 T stringColor(char*)
000000000000005a T ANSI_SEQUENCE(int, int)
0000000000000000 T get_next_CONSOLE_BUFFER()
0000000000000196 T BG(int)
0000000000000178 T FG(int)
000000000000015d T BGCC(CONSOLE_COLORS)
0000000000000142 T FGCC(CONSOLE_COLORS)
000000000000003c B next_console_buffer
U sprintf

This has a function FG(int) which basically outputs the ANSI escape sequence chars for that color.

Color               Foreground  Background
Black               [30m   [40m
etc..

Anyway - you can see it named in the object reference list above.

I also compile the terminal program filelist.c -> filelist.o into which I now have code like this.
"(char *)FG(RED)"

See below for the whole function

void msg_usage_exit(char *fmt, ...)
{
char buf[MYMAXPATH*4];

```
va_list arglist;
va_start(arglist, fmt);
(void) vsprintf((char *)(buf), fmt, arglist);
va_end(arglist);
fprintf(stderr,"%s%s%s\n",(char *)FG(RED),(char *)buf,(char *)OFF());
fprintf(stderr,"\nUsage: %s [/R][/B][/F] {single folder name}"
                    "\n/R = Recursive from starting folder"
                    "\n/B = Bare - filename only"
                    "\n/F = Full system path [otherwise just relative to starting path]", iam);
exit(0);
```

}

When i dump that listing I get these symbols - and FG is listed.
$ nm filelist.o -C
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 N .debug_abbrev
0000000000000000 N .debug_aranges
0000000000000000 N .debug_frame
0000000000000000 N .debug_info
0000000000000000 N .debug_line
0000000000000000 N .debug_line_str
0000000000000000 N .debug_rnglists
0000000000000000 N .debug_str
0000000000000000 p .pdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata
0000000000000000 r .rdata$.refptr.alphasort
0000000000000000 r .rdata$zzz
0000000000000000 R .refptr.alphasort
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000000 r .xdata
U FG
U ___chkstk_ms
U __errno
U __getreent
U __locale_ctype_ptr
U __main
U alphasort
U asctime
0000000000000048 B context
0000000000000000 D envsStr
U exit
U fprintf
U free
U fwrite
U getenv
0000000000000040 B glob_files
0000000000000060 B iam
0000000000001060 b level0pathlen.0
0000000000000000 B levelPathLengths
U localtime
0000000000000a10 T main
0000000000000000 T msg_usage_exit
U printf
00000000000000bd T scanThisDir
U scandir
U sprintf
U stat
U strerror
U strlen
U strncpy
0000000000000018 D target
U time
U toupper
U vsprintf

When i try and link it all i get this error

$ gcc filelist.o ansiColorbasic.o -o filelist.exe

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: filelist.o: in function `msg_usage_exit': /home/Craig/c/filelist.c:58: undefined reference to` FG'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

So it is saying (I think) that it cannot resolve FG between the 2x object files.. and yet it is there..

Any ideas ?
It is all from the same win10 machine, but different dev stacks - one is vs2012 and one is cygwin

I even COPIED the code from VS2012 into the cygwin home path and tried compiling that. No change.

I have hit the wall with what is pretty basic code-base functionality not working..

Any suggestions.?

Link of 2x objects failed.

nm of both objects show the same module named. One as defn. One as external usage.

link error

$ gcc filelist.o ansiColorbasic.o -o filelist.exe
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: filelist.o: in function `msg_usage_exit': /home/Craig/c/filelist.c:58: undefined reference to` FG'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

And yet FG is in the ansiColorbasic.o object being linked in..

Comment: It looks like you are using C++ in there. In which case just forget about it, it won't work.